# Implement Dropbox .gitignore

Tags: git, dropbox

I use dropbox to store all my documents, including my programming projects. The only drawback there is to using it is the fact that it syncs all the useless dependencies. Unfortunately, there is no such things as a `.dropboxignore` file. Would it be possible to implement this functionality myself using the `.gitignore` file I already have? I want it to be completely automagical.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [great article](https://peter.grman.at/ignore-node_modules-in-dropbox/) written by someone who was experiencing similar frustrations with dropbox as you are.

In the article, Peter describes two solutions:

- [DropboxIgnore](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/6c8a563e248103baaa20) - a small bash script which uses the Dropbox CLI to ignore files, only available for Linux.
- [.dbignore](http://konolige.com/dbignore/) - <strike>a .gitignore-like solution, only available for mac OS</strike>

  - Note: *This solution is no longer supported nor maintained*

---

*Please note that I have not used these products, nor do I have any affiliation with the developers.*

Comment: I did some searching but didn’t find these, thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that .dbignore does not work with any recent versions of Dropbox and is no longer actively maintained.

Comment: Thanks @geerlingguy, I've updated the answer to account for the deprecation of `.dbignore`

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for others on Windows and Powershell with the git command line tool installed.

The script finds all .gitignore files in current folder and subfolder and sets the ignored files and folders to not upload to Dropbox.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | `
Where-Object { $_.Name -eq '.gitignore' } | `
ForEach-Object { `
    Write-Host $_.DirectoryName; `
    Push-Location $_.DirectoryName; `
    git status --ignored --short | `
        Where-Object { $_.StartsWith('!! ') } | `
        ForEach-Object { `
            $ignore = $_.Split(' ')[1].Trim('/'); `
            Write-Host $ignore; `
            Set-Content -Path $ignore -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1 `
        }; `
    Pop-Location }
```

You can paste this into say `dropbox-sync-ignore.ps1` and store in your PATH and run it whenever you start or update a project in git.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox allows you to [ignore specific folders or files](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files) without excluding them, therefore, you could implement a script that will find files based on your `.gitignore` files and ignore them.

I recently implemented [dropboxignore](https://github.com/sp1thas/dropboxignore) which is a simple shell script that creates `.dropboxignore` files based on existing `.gitignore` files in order to ignore the matched files from dropbox.

**Note**: dropboxignore is currently available only for Linux and MacOS.

Comment: This is very awesome solution, however, I couldn't get the proper result of "dropboxignore ignore ~/demo". It's successfully generate the dropboxignore, but I always got the 0 number of ignored files or folders on my Mac.

Comment: @imleoson thank you for your feedback, feel free to open an issue [here](https://github.com/sp1thas/dropboxignore/issues)

Comment: It’s been solved now, it was missing another library. Once installed all required libraries, it works perfectly now.